# Warning in Package hyperref: /PageLabels entry

Tags: hyperref, warnings, resume, href

I am getting this warning `Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry`, when I use `\href` in `res.cls`. 
How can I eliminate the warning?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[line,margin,11pt]{res} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}
\usepackage[%
colorlinks=true,%
urlcolor=blue%
]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\name{Name}

\address{1414 XXX} % address 1
\address{E-mail: \href{mailto:aaa@xx.edu}{aaa@xx.edu}} % address 2

\begin{resume}
\section{Education}{My University}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the res class issues a `\nofiles`, so no aux-file and other auxiliary files are written and hyperref has no chance to do its work. Don't use the class if you want hyperlinks, it is from 2000/05/19.

Comment: hyperref works here. I just get the warning, and want to get rid of that. Do you have any suggestion like what can I use instead of res.cls?

Comment: without auxiliary files a number of hyperref functions (e.g. bookmarks) won't work. There are a number of cv-classes on ctan but I have no real opinion which one to use https://ctan.org/topic/cv. Looks for one that looks new and maintained.